# Duplicate string literal found - Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I got a problem on my Java code on Android Studio:
I got this warning " Duplicate string literal found in   'com.example.xyz.MainActivity' " on my code on ConnectThread (private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");) and on MainActivity ( UUID applicationUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); ) subprograms. Both of them should be used for a bluetooth connection on a phone apk connection to other device.
What should I do and what you recommend to me?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

This means that you have given same name to 2 variables. Variable names can not be repeated. Please look in your file if you have a duplicate variable.

Answer (score 0):

it says that you have duplicated variable:

```
"00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
```

To avoid this warning you should extract it to the constant:

```
private static final String HASH = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"
```

and then use HASH variable instead a literal:

```
UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString(HASH);

UUID applicationUUID = UUID.fromString(HASH);
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the solution. I changed it in my code and the warning has gone.